# Django : Excluded fields are saved

Tags: django, forms, models

I have a model :

```
from django.db import models
from tinymce.models import HTMLField

class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Team name')
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Team city')
    biography = HTMLField(verbose_name='Team biography')
    country = models.ForeignKey('Country')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Country name')
    code = models.CharField(max_length=5, verbose_name='Country code')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.code
```

And a form for this model:

```
from django import forms
from teams.models import Team

class TeamForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Team
        fields = (
            'biography',
            'city',
            'country'
        )
```

And this is my view:

```
def add(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TeamForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            send = True
            form.save()
    else:
        form = TeamForm()
    return render(request, 'teams/add.html', locals())
```

As you can see, all my model fields are required because I don't add argument 'null' to True in my model attributes.
In my ModelForm, for testing, I just specify fields biography, city and country.

But when I fill the form and send-it, data are saved in database, however is missing name and slug....

Why dont i have a django exception ?
Thanks for youre help

Comment: Is that your real indentation? You save regardless of whether valid or not

Comment: edited but i have the same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither of those fields are saved as Null, though. They are both character fields (SlugField is a subclass of CharField), and an empty charfield is saved as an empty string - which is perfectly valid from the database point of view.

Comment: Ok so mysql save it has empty strings ??

Comment: And for example, if i dont fill the field city in form page, I have a error message ...

Comment: Well, yes, the city field is on your form.

Comment: I don't understand.

Comment: My model can save name and slug as empty string, but in my form, if i dont specify a value for a field, it can't save it ?

Comment: Yes. Why would the form validate fields that it doesn't contain? Why would you want it to?

Comment: Ok, form doesn't run validations on non-specified fields. Thank you

Comment: My course say "However, when creating a new entry, if certain mandatory fields of the model (those that do not have null = True as argument) were excluded, do not forget to add them later. So do not call the save method as it is on a ModelForm with excluded fields, otherwise Django will throw an exception."